# If $\{1,2,3,...,9\}$ is divided into three groups prove that product of numbers of one group exceeds $71$.

Tags: number-theory

I have to show that-

> If $\{1,2,3,...,9\}$ is divided into three groups prove that product of numbers of one group exceeds $71$.

I tried using pigeon hole principle but things are becoming increasingly difficult for three groups.I might have been able to show for two groups but how to show it for $3$ groups?

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: $71^3<9!$, hence it is not possible that every group has a product of its elements $\leq 71$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: $\sqrt[3]{9!}\approx71.327$, and any product of integers is an integer.

Comment: What do you *cube root*?

Comment: @tatan: $9!$. It’s the product of the three group products.

Comment: When we cube root we assume the equality of the three sets....why do we take that strategy?

Comment: @tatan It may be easier to understand if you consider the equivalent form $$71^3 \lt 9!$$

Comment: @tatan: Because if the product of three numbers is more than $x^3$, then at least one of the three numbers must be more than $x$. It’s exactly like arguing that since $\frac{45}4>11$, if you divide the same numbers into $4$ groups, at least one group must have a sum greater than $11$.

Answer (score 4):

We have $\sqrt[3]{9!}>71{}{}$.